# Query for a single data relationship in many-to-many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a database that contain Worker table and Location table. A worker can work in multiple locations and a location can have multiple workers. They are being connected in WorkerLocation table in which workerID and locationID is the bridge. How can I get a list of a Location that assigned to a single worker to display? Right now, the code I have show the relationship of the worker and location but not the location itself.

```
var assignedLocation = dbContext.WorkerLocations.Where(x => x.workerID == userID).ToList();
```

Comment: Does it help you `var assignedLocation = dbContext.Worker.where(x=> x.workerID == userID).Include(wl=> wl.WorkerLocations)`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be :

```
var assignedLocation = dbContext.Worker.where(x=> x.workerID == userID).Include(wl=> wl.WorkerLocations).ThenInclude(loc=> loc.Location).FirstOrDefault();
```

Have a try with this one and let me know if it works! Happy Coding!

Comment: It said that ThenInclude IQueryable does not contain definition for ThenInclude.

Comment: Your problem might be a missing reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational?

This can be added through the package manager.

Also ensure you are using .include from the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace and not the other .Include (which does not have a .ThenInclude)

Comment: @MortenBork is correct, if you are using visual studio then go to nuget package manager and type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, before installing please check for mached dotnet/dotnetcore version. Otherwise it won't work. Then it will work. And if you face further problems then please share the code fully.

Comment: I'm using C#.NET, not C#.NET Core so it doens't work for me

Comment: 1: Check you actually have the data available in the database. (Workers, locations, and their M:M)

2: Check your connection is actually referencing the correct database, if you have multiple. 

3: Check your model (EDMX file) to verify that it has been able to establish your relations correctly. 

4: Pull a single object out, and debug it's navigation properties to check that your loading principle is taking the navigation properties into the models. 

5: Display your results following steps 1-4 if you still have a problem.